# Populating ListBox using parameterized query on VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, data-binding

I have the following code that involves populating a `ListBox`. How can I parameterize the query to prevent SQL injection?

```
    sqlCon = New SqlConnection(strConn)
    sqlCon.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM employees where id = & textbox1.text &"
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlCon)
    Dim da As New DataTable
    adapter.Fill(da)
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "employees"
    ListBox1.DataSource = da
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "employees"
    sqlCon.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
Using sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConn)
    sqlCon.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id = @id"
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlCon)
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", textbox1.Text))

    Dim da As New DataTable
    adapter.Fill(da)

    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "employees"
    ListBox1.DataSource = da
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "employees"
End Using
```

It's better to enclose the code inside the `Using` so that the `SqlConnection` will be disposed even an exception is thrown. Also instead of using `SELECT *`, you may want to specify the column names.